# Word alignment works only in case of byte addressable memory?

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu-architecture, terminology, memory-alignment

Here there is a definition of word alignment

> Words are said to be Aligned in memory if they begin at a byte-address that is a multiple of the number of bytes in a word.
> https://educatech.in/word-alignment/

But what if I don't have a byte-addressable memory?

In fact, what is the exact general definition of word alignment? Do we ONLY talk about word alignment in case of byte addressable memory?

What is an alignment in case I have a N-bits-addressable memory and a B-bits word size?

Comment: For this purpose you can think of `byte` as the minimal addressable unit, not necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: Minimal addressable unit is equal to N ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

Word-addressable memory makes misaligned word accesses impossible because there's literally not an address for anything except the starts of whole words.  There are no low bits of the address to be 0.  Exactly like byte accesses on a byte-addressable machine.

(In terms of byte-addressable memory, you could maybe think of those byte-within-word bits as being implicitly zero on a word-addressable machine.  But normally we say they just don't exist at all, so addresses are still word-sized, like 32-bit not 32+2 or something.)

A word-addressable machine with load-pair / store-pair instructions or something else like SIMD which can access multiple words with a single instruction *could* have a concept of (mis)alignment, for the same reason as a byte-addressable machine with 2-byte words.

---

On a word-addressable machine that only supports single-word access size, you could say the whole concept of alignment is irrelevant or doesn't exist.  (Very early computers were like that, I think; alignment didn't become a thing until later.)

Or you could say (e.g. if designing a cache, load/store units, or a bus interface for a modern DSP or something) that choosing to make the machine word-addressable means you don't have to *handle* the possibility of mis-aligned or byte accesses, simplifying the design.

Comment: I don't get it? If the memory is word-addressed, then every address is word-aligned!

Comment: @JeanDujardin: Yes, exactly, that's what my answer says.

Comment: But in the question I did not asked about the case of word-addressable memory, but in the case that N bits are adressable (where N is not always a byte of 8 bits)

Comment: @JeanDujardin: Then as  
500 - Internal Server Error commented, your "N-bit-addressable memory" is your byte size.  If your word size isn't a multiple of it, that's extremely weird and I don't think there is a normal definition of alignment for that case, unless the machine has loads/stores that are LCM(byte bits, word bits) that read/write multiple words at once.  (And BTW, don't say B-bit words, that's the worst possible letter because you want B to indicate bytes.)